# question about GlassFish/Tomcat security realms

Tags: security, jsf, tomcat, glassfish, jdbcrealm

I have GlassFish set up to use "JDBCRealm".  The configuration looks like this and it works fine:

```
<JDBCRealm userTable="users" userNameCol="user_name" 
userCredCol="user_pass" userRoleTable="user_roles" 
roleNameCol="role_name" ... />
```

My database currently looks like this:

```
- USERS -
USER_NAME | USER_PASS
steve | password1

- USER_ROLES -
USER_NAME | ROLE_NAME
steve | ADMIN
```

My question is, if I want to normalize the data in the database, how do I configure a realm that can understand the new database design?  Do I have to write a custom "realm" object or something like that?

Instead, I want my database to look something this:

```
- USERS -
USER_ID | USER_NAME | USER_PASS
1 | steve | password1

- ROLES -
ROLE_ID | ROLE_NAME
2 | ADMIN

- USER_ROLES -
USER_ID | ROLE_ID
1 | 2
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work straightforward. I just did it a few days ago for Glassfish server. But I think it should be similar for Tomcat. I have 3 tables:

- user (login (pk), password, ...)
- group (group_id (pk), group_name)
- group_has_user (login (fk from user table), group_id (fk from group table))

my JDBC Realm looks like the following:

```
<auth-realm name="Register-User" classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm">
          <property name="jaas-context" value="jdbcRealm" />
          <property name="datasource-jndi" value="jdbc/ladb" />
          <property name="user-table" value="user" />
          <property name="user-name-column" value="login" />
          <property name="password-column" value="password" />
          <property name="group-table" value="group_has_user" />
          <property name="group-name-column" value="group_id" />
          <property name="digest-algorithm" value="SHA-256" />
```

If you experience problems, make shure that the columns group_id have the same name in group table and in the join-table.

Answer (score 0):

The way we tackle this issue is to normalize the database and create views for glassfish.

```
                      Table "public.admin"
    Column     |            Type             | Modifiers 
---------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id            | bigint                      | not null
 login         | character varying(255)      | not null
 password      | character varying(255)      | not null


             Table "public.role"
 Column |          Type          | Modifiers 
--------+------------------------+-----------
 id     | bigint                 | not null
 name   | character varying(255) | 



  Table "public.role_admins"
  Column  |  Type  | Modifiers 
----------+--------+-----------
 role_id  | bigint | not null
 admin_id | bigint | not null
```

Here is the view:

```
           View "public.v_admin_role"
  Column   |          Type          | Modifiers 
-----------+------------------------+-----------
 login     | character varying(255) | 
 password  | character varying(255) | 
 role_name | character varying(255) | 
View definition:
 SELECT a.login, a.password, r.name AS role_name
   FROM admin a
   JOIN role_admins ra ON ra.admin_id = a.id
   JOIN role r ON r.id = ra.role_id
  WHERE a.active = true;
```

And the config

```
<auth-realm classname="com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.jdbc.JDBCRealm" name="gcsiadmin">
  <property name="user-name-column" value="login"/>
  <property name="password-column" value="password"/>
  <property name="group-name-column" value="role_name"/>
  <property name="datasource-jndi" value="jdbc/GcsiDS"/>
  <property name="user-table" value="v_admin_role"/>
  <property name="group-table" value="v_admin_role"/>
  <property name="jaas-context" value="jdbcRealm"/>
</auth-realm>
```